# .NET MAUI MVVM Picker binding to a list

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, maui, picker

I've got to be missing something dumb or obvious but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I've got a list of objects in my viewmodel that I'm trying to bind to a picker and display the 'Name' property of the objects in the picker.

The view is aware of the list of objects (which is exposed as an observable property (community toolkit mvvm)), but I cannot access any of the properties inside the objects to display, resulting in a blank entry in the picker's display for each object in the list.

```csharp
public partial class SettingsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public Settings settingsObj;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public List<Language> langs;

    SettingsService settingsService;
    IConnectivity connectivity;

    public TextToSpeechSettingsPageViewModel(SettingsService settingsXMLServices, IConnectivity connectivitys)
    {
        this.settingsService = settingsXMLServices;
        this.connectivity = connectivitys;

        settingsObj = Task.Run(() => settingsService.GetSettingsAsync()).Result;

        Langs = settingsObj.Languages.Language;
    }
}
```

so up above, I'm populating the Langs observable property with settingsObj.Languages.Language which returns a poplated List

in the XAML View, I've attempted to bind as directed by various examples I've found (note there's a lot more to the view but I'm only showing the relevant parts:

```csharp
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyAppName.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:SettingsPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MyAppName.Pages.SettingsPage"
             Title="Settings"
             x:Name="SettingsPage">
```

```csharp
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                        <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Language:"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="LangSetting" SelectedIndexChanged="LangSetting_SelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Langs, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Langs.Name}">
                        </Picker>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Intellisense recognises Langs and will give me either Capacity or Count, but not access to the properties inside an instance of the class. It's like it can't see the actual objects inside but just that it's a list. If I just try to put Name instead of Langs.Name I get the same result.

How do I get it to show me the properties associated with the objects in the list?

Comment: use `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: I could have sworn that didn't work before but it works now! I do still get an error in the XAML page with a partial squiggly under Name that says 'Member not found in data context SettingsPageViewModel' Do you know how I could resolve this?

Comment: Picker is using two different datasources and Intellisense is not smart enough to figure that out.  I would just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

So the answer as per Jason in the comment replies was

ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"

I had assumed that it wouldn't work because there was a squiggly under Name that stated that the member was not found in the data context, however that does not actually prevent it from working.

Comment: Per [Populate a Picker with data using data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker?view=net-maui-7.0), setting the `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"` property to the required property should work. BTW, you can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: set the x:DataType to help with the squiggly underline, or set the source on the binding.